# com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

When trying to build my Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2022 I am receiving this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete, origin: obj\Debug\120\lp\100\jl\bin\classes.jar : com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzai.class
```

My build log shows this:

```
Error in obj\Debug\120\lp\100\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzai.class:

Type com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzai is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\120\lp\100\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzai.class, obj\Debug\120\lp\101\jl\bin\classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/measurement/internal/zzai.class
```

I have used 7zip to extract the specified zzai.class file however I don't know what to do from here. Trying to edit the file in notepad++ just shows noninterpretable code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by uninstalling unnecessary NuGet packages for Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement, only keeping the dependent packages required for Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics:

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement.Api

Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Measurement.Sdk